# Convert Lat/Lon to Integer

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

A service that I'm consuming requires that I pass it the lat/lon for an address as integers. Currently, my lat/lon's are stored as doubles:

```
double lat = 38.898748;
double lon = -77.037684;
```

I've exhausted my Google-fu and can't find a method for converting lat/lon to an integer representation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need specs (or examples)  from that service. There are multiple ways to do that.

Comment: Did you want rounded degrees? Or somthing with a bit more precision? Rounded minutes or seconds maybe? As Henk says, it depends.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'll have to email their support.

Comment: Assuming no fractions of a second do you just need to convert it to a number of the form [+-][0-90][0-60][0-60]? What API are you using?

Comment: Well, emailed support and they said multiply by 1 million. I always hesitate to call because their information is less than accurate at times.

Comment: Just to check, it does exepect __2__ integers, right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yes, two ints. I just finished testing the multiply by 1 million approach and it worked. Honestly, it seems crazy to ask for ints for something that is typically stored as a double. It's also crazy that the API docs don't include the multiply by 1 million information.

Comment: You didn't even say what your doubles are. Is it "what google uses" maybe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes it is simple, just multiply by 1 million.

Multiply by .000001 to convert back.

Granted this assumes you only want precision to the 6th decimal.

Comment: Although this conversion works you (based on your acceptance of the answer) you should nevertheless check your and your provider's Geodetic Systems. Many are quite similar and differences may not show up or be negligible/unnoticeable in many instances but they can extreme in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

You need to know what [Geodetic System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system) you're using and what the API expects. E.g. WGS84, NAD83, OSGB36, ED50... (Example: [Google Earth uses WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Earth))

If they need an integer then they're probably using something different from Google and other providers. Chances are that rounding a a double or some other integer conversion will not work. You need the Geodetic System information and then make the conversion between the two values.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can see this happening is if you shift the decimal point.

```
int lat = (int)(38.898748 * 1000000.0);
int lon = (int)(-77.037684 * 1000000.0);
```

Comment: But why not `10000000` or `10000`?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - It doesn't really matter multiplying by either would give you the wrong answer.

Comment: @Henk - If you use your noggin you'll notice that his example uses 6 digit precision. He could actually use any precision.

Comment: @Ramhound - You could be right but the OP accepted an answer similar to mine. I do however find it a bit unfair that I received a down-vote while the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the coordinates in seconds, just multiply by `60 * 60`:

```
int latitude = (int)Math.Round(lat * 60.0 * 60.0);
int longitude = (int)Math.Round(lon * 60.0 * 60.0);
```

If you need the coodinates in higher resolution, for example 100th of a second, just multiply by 100 more.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: This criticism goes to 90% of all who weighted in on this question, and shows clearly why it should've been asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

  IF you work with coordinates, you MUST at least know the earth is not uniform, and there exists more coordinate systems than "what google maps uses nowadays".

  And I'm quite sure I read GMaps changed (some finer details of) their coordinate system along the way, but for most down to earth use cases just remember "WGS84".

Answer (score 2):

I am going to take a wild stab at this and guess that you are wanting to convert pure degrees to Degrees:Minutes:Seconds in the form of a single integer.

Here is one way you could convert this into an integer, but obviously you are going to want to confirm this is the format they are using.

```
double originalLat = 38.898748,
    TEMPdecimal;

int degrees = (int)originalLat;

TEMPdecimal = (originalLat - degrees) * 60;

int minutes = (int)TEMPdecimal;

TEMPdecimal = (TEMPdecimal - minutes) * 60;

int seconds = (int)TEMPdecimal;

int lat = (degrees * 10000) + (minutes * 100) + seconds;
```

In this case the return is 385355 or 38 degrees 53 minutes 55 seconds.  Sorry if this looks a little sloppy and the type casting might not be the most efficient (definitely would need to make sure it rounds properly, i think type casting to int is rounding down all the time) but it will give you longitude/latitude.

Comment: I came across this strange format in a dataset. This answer explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be either,

```
int FactorConversion(double degrees)
{
    return (int) degrees * MagicConversionFactor 
    //You supply this number, a likely candidate is 360 since
    //this converts degrees to seconds 
}
```

or

```
 int BinaryConversion32(float degrees)
 {
     return BitConvetor.ToInt32(BitConvertor.GetBytes(degrees))
 }
```

or

```
long BinaryConversion64(double degrees)
{
    return BitConvetor.ToInt64(BitConvertor.GetBytes(degrees))
}
```

note that double is an 8 byte type. As previously stated by me and others, it all rather depends on what the API expects.

The second two options would be lossless but bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

```
double_lat = 38.898748;

double_lon = -77.037684;
```

A simple way to store decimal positions as integers:

```
lat = (double_lat + 90) * 1000000;

lon = (double_lon + 180) * 1000000;

lat = 128898748;
lon = 102962316;
```